# Seaborn module 'histplot' not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I am running seaborn on pycharm. However when I'm running the `histplot` module, it says there are no module in that name. However, the seaborn version is the latest (0.11.0) and the python version I'm using is `3.6.2`. Where is the error?

Comment: You're most likely using a different python installation in Pycharm, check which python interpreter Pycharm is using.

Comment: I've checked, it says python 3.6

Comment: Run a python interpreter outside of Pycharm and try to `import histplot`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'histplot'. Yes i got the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the error with seaborn version `0.10.0`and `0.11.0`. I believe you are not using `0.11.0` as the `histplot` is a method under the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) of version `0.11.0`. Check the version using:

```
import seaborn as sns
print(sns.__version__)
```

Code from @StupidWolf produces the following results with `0.11.0`.  :

[image]

I could reproduce the error in `0.10.0`. Therefore, I would suggest to reinstall/upgrade seaborn with the following:

```
pip install seaborn==0.11.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`histplot` is a function under seaborn, so if you do:

```
import histplot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fc88c9bf8fe2> in <module>
----> 1 import histplot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'histplot'
```

You need to do:

```
import seaborn as sns
data = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.histplot(data['sepal_length'])
```